# How to find compatable cassette for older Shimano

Tags: parts, cassette, freewheel, tools

I have a 2002 Diamondback Oakpiont. The derailleur says c201. Is it freewheel or cassette? If it's cassette, the last gear seems to be the nut (12 notches). Here is link to the bike [on Bikepedia](http://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2002&brand=Diamondback&model=Oakpoint).

How do I get the right cogs/freewheel? And will this [tool set](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C6ZQN02) work for my needs?

Comment: I'd guess cassette since 8 speed freewheels are rather rare. Can you post a picture of the hub? See this link for identifying cassette vs freewheel: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/free-k7.html

Comment: Cassette removal needs two tools. A chain whip and cassette lock ring remover. The tool kit you linked to is more than needed for this job, and contains a few tools only needed for newer bikes (post 2000). Tools kits with fewer tools might be cheaper (e.g. https://www.amazon.com/FANTASYCART-Universal-Mechanics-Bicycle-44pcs/dp/B0019J6ZLE/ref=sr_1_8?s=sporting-goods&ie=UTF8&qid=1467764893&sr=1-8&keywords=bicycle+tool+kit) . I do recommend a tools kit such as these if you plan on you own maintenance, they pay for themselves very quickly compared to relying on the LBS for simple jobs .

Comment: The Essential kit from Nashbar is a good starting point, but most of the tools you can build as you go with higher quality tools (but will cost more; a Park Tool SR-11 and FR-5 will be more than the kit). You'll also be using a chain tool to replace your chain and a big crescent wrench to help you remove the cassette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your rear wheel off and visually inspect the cassette.   Compare with this answer https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/21406/19705  and see which  you have.

Given bikepedia says 8 speed, its most likely to be a cassette.

---

This is a freehub with a cassette.   Note the ring of indentations just inside where it says 12T.  That silver ring will unscrew and all the cogs can slide off.

[image]

By comparison,this is a freewheel.  If you undid the black lock ring then the guts of the freewheel will still be on the wheel.

[image]

Image credits to Sheldon Brown's website http://sheldonbrown.com/free-k7.html

Comment: I have a cassette from you pics. Are all shimano cassettes universal on shimano? How do I identify the right cassette? Is there a number somewhere on the cassette cogs or keeper? I see hyperglide on the example pic keeper on lock nut. I'll check mine

Comment: I have a hyperglide too. HG in shimano part #. I will try to vote for you not sure how yet.